# Controlling a GUI application remotely

Tags: c#, user-interface, remote-access

There's an application written in C# that doesn't have any means of remote controlling. The only use scenario possible is to click the buttons with the mouse to get some result.

I'd like to create a server that would expose some common usage scenario with pre-defined clicking logic. So for example the application has a button "do thing" and I'm willing to make an HTTP (or other) server that would click it when a certain URL is loaded.

The application is intended to be used on Windows, though it should work fine with wine - my primary OS is Ubuntu, but I think that running the app in a VM is a better option. To program the rest of of the logic I can use java, python, ruby, php or node.js (I don't know C#).

What is the best approach to handle this? I would prefer not relying on click at the predefined X*Y position on the screen. Ideally the solution would also allow reading the data back.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily automate the gui using the ui automation api. Check for example the White framework on codeplex

http://white.codeplex.com/

I am not sure however if yiu will be able to easily expose such automated application from an application server. The automation is not possible without explicit user session with visible desktop interface thus limiting your server processing to one active session at a time.

Comment: No, you can use any .net language to code against it, this is how .net works.

Comment: Well, as I stated in the question I only know "java, python, ruby, php or node.js".